# Update/toggle and get text of command button when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Im looking to update the command button text on a kendo grid row when clicked, and then.
button is as follows:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("View ARs").Click("showAnnReviewByPlan"));
```

Its calling a javascript method to load a partial view and show another sub grid, which I'd like to then hide if the button is clicked again. I can update the text to say 'Hide' by using -

```
$(".k-grid-ViewARs").html("<span class=' '></span>Hide ARs");
```

But I think this will update all rows, and not just the row where the button resides.
I cannot work out how to then get the text so I can toggle it back when clicked again. Probably simple but its eluding me.

***Update***

```
var buttonText = $(".k-grid-ViewARs").html();

    if (buttonText.indexOf("Hide ARs") !== -1)
```

This allows me to get the button text and toggle it, so that part is ok, but I need to get the button only for the specific row I've clicked on.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. See comments in code for explanation.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function showAnnReviewByPlan(e)
{
    // Set text to 'Hide AR's'
    var buttonText = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").find(".k-grid-ViewARs").html(); // $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").... gets specific row & element containing button text, in this case <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-ViewARs"

    if (buttonText.indexOf("Hide ARs") !== -1)
    {
        $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").find(".k-grid-ViewARs").html("<span class=' '></span>View ARs"); // toggles/sets specific row button text

        // Hide #AnnReviewsByPlan <div>
        $("#AnnReviewsByPlan").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").find(".k-grid-ViewARs").html("<span class=' '></span>Hide ARs"); // toggles/sets specific row button text

        // Make sure #AnnReviewsByPlan <div> is visible
        $("#AnnReviewsByPlan").show();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        var id = dataItem.id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/ManageCompanies/AnnualReviewsByPlan',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#AnnReviewsByPlan').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```